# Parse '1/2' from string Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I am having a string that I need to parse and get number in required format like'1/2' from string

Example :- Take 1/2 bowl of water

I want to extract from the above string .

Currently I am Trying to use Regex to Extract this required text.

Code that I am currently using To Check If String Has Numbers and Extract that Numbers  -

```
function hasNumbers(t) {
//To check if string has numbers
  return /\d/.test(t);
}

function getNumberFromString(txt) {
//To extract number in 1/2 from string but currently it is giving '12' instead of '1/2'
  var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
  numb = numb.join("");
  return numb;
}
```

Comment: Just add the slash `txt.match(/[0-9/]/g);`

Comment: Thank you for the answer , Its working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return /[0-9/]/g.test(t);
```

[image]

Since this gives `true`, you can use `.match().join()` to get what you want:

```
t.match(/[0-9/]/g).join("");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
function hasNumbers(t) {
//To check if string has numbers
return /[0-9/]/.test(t);
}

function getNumberFromString(txt) {
//To extract number in 1/2 from string but currently it is giving '12' instead of '1/2'
var numb = txt.match(/[0-9/]/g);
numb = numb.join("");
return numb;
}

alert(getNumberFromString("1/2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `\/` in the input of your `match` function:

`var numb = txt.match(/[\d\/]/g);`